# What is the char in C for the int value 10? Where I can look up this?

Tags: c

I have a character in a char-Array which I get with fputs(). But it contains a char which is getting count by the function strlen(). I decide to give me out the int value of this char to see where the problem is.

As char I can see nothing. Thought its a Whitespace but not sure. Would like if someone could tell me what it is and explain why it is there.

```
printf("%d",(int) input[6]); //--> give me the value of 10 out.
```

Comment: Any half-decent C programming book has an ASCII table.

Comment: You can find ASCII 10 code at the end of each line.

Comment: @Lundin Sure K&R has got one?

Comment: Googlng 'ASCII table' works fine.

Comment: Can you suggest a good C-Programming Book? Our lectures about C was horrible bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `10` is the ASCII value for the newline character (LF, or linefeed). Closely related is character `13`, which is CR, or carriage return, which, on Windows systems, often precedes the LF character. I would suggest getting a copy of the ASCII table (they're all over the web) and referencing it from time to time.

Character `10` can be represented by `'\n'` in C code, as well as `'\012'`, `'\x0a'`, and `'\u000a'`
Character `13` (carriage return) can be represented by `'\r'`, `'\015'`, `'\x0d'`, and `'\u000d'`.

Comment: Worth noting perhaps that in C it is represented by the escape sequence `\n`.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination! I thought strlen() would already kill escape sequence's.

Comment: @missjohanna - What do you mean by "kill?"

Comment: @missjohanna C character escape sequences only appear in the source code, not in the compiled program, so there is nothing to "kill".

Comment: I meant that it isnt count as char in a char-array while using strlen(). The '\0' isnt count aswell.

Comment: `strlen` stops at the first null (`'\0'`) character, and counts all others. You should probably read up on the documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is the newline (LF  (NL line feed, new line)) in `ASCII`. See all of the values [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html).

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by the others, the character 10 in ASCII is LF (line feed).

If you wanted `printf` to output the character (not see its ordinal value), you could use the `%c` format specifier to pass a single character.

Example:

```
printf("-%c-", input[6]);
```

should yield:

```
-
-
```

I.e. two dashes separated by a line feed. Please keep in mind that the outcome on Windows depends on how your C runtime handles a single LF without CR as on Windows a line break is customarily represented by CRLF instead of just LF which is the standard on unixoid systems. The only exception to that rule were old Mac systems which used to use only CR to encode a line break.